# Establishing a bound of the form $\frac{\cosh(x)}{\cosh(y)} \le \cosh(M(x-y)) $

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, exponential-function, hyperbolic-functions

> Suppose we have $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ where $0 \le y \le x$. I'm trying to establish a bound of the form
> $$ \frac{\cosh(x)}{\cosh(y)} \le \cosh(M(x-y)) $$
> where $M$ is a positive constant.

Trial and error has shown that this probably holds for $M = 2$, but I'm having a hard time proving this.

Does anyone have any idea how I could establish this?

Answer (score 2):

The estimate does not hold for *any* positive constant $M$ and all $0 < y \le x$:

$$
 \cosh(x) \le \cosh(y) \cdot \cosh(M(x-y))
$$
is equivalent to
$$
 \frac{\cosh(x)-\cosh(y)}{x-y} \le \cosh(y) \cdot \frac{\cosh(M(x-y))-1}{M(x-y)} \cdot M
$$
and taking the limit $x \to y$ gives
$$
  \sinh(y) \le \cosh(y) \cdot 0 \cdot M = 0 
$$
which is impossible for positive $y$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true.  At $(x,y)=(7.4,7.2)$ we calculate numerically:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\cosh(x)}{\cosh(y)}=\frac{\cosh(7.4)}{\cosh(7.2)}&\approx 1.221\\
\cosh(2(x-y))=\cosh(0.4)&\approx 1.081
\end{align*}

In fact, there can be no $M$ that works:

Expanding LHS at small $x-y$ gives
$$
\frac{\cosh(x)}{\cosh(y)}=1+\tanh(y)(x-y)+o(x-y)
$$
but the RHS expands as
$$
\cosh(M(x-y))=1+o(x-y)
$$
so as long as $y$ is large, you can find $x-y$ small enough to beat the bound.  The example suggests something along the line $x,y\approx e^M$ and $x-y\approx e^{-M}$.